# Mongodb: Search on top-level document and sub-document

Tags: mongodb

I have following documents. Imaging the top level document is an adult(as a person), it has `attribute1` and `array` and **optional** `kids`, where each element of `kids` is also a person with an additional `attribute2` compared to adult. `ID` will be unique.  Some adults have kids some don't. A kid will always comes under an adult. I want to search either a top level adult or a kid.

```
[
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "attribute1": "123",
    "array": [
      {
        "field1": "f1"
      }
    ],
    "kids": [
      {
        "ID": "2",
        "attribute1": "456",
        "attribute2": "222",
        "array": [
          {
            "field1": "f2"
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        "ID": "3",
        "attribute1": "567",
        "attribute2": "222",
        "array": [
          {
            "field1": "f3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": "4",
    "attribute1": "123",
    "array": [
      {
        "field1": "f4"
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

Now if I search a person(either an kid or an adult) with `ID`=1 `attribute1`="123" and `field1`="f1" it should only return

```
{
    "ID": "1",
    "attribute1": "123",
    "array": [
      {
        "field1": "f1"
      }
    ],
}
```

If I search `ID`=2 , `attribute1`="456", `attribute2`="222" and `field1`="f2" it should return

```
{
        "ID": "2",
        "attribute1": "456",
        "attribute2": "222",
        "array": [
          {
            "field1": "f2"
          }
        ]
}
```

Please help! playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/OMnI_cxEX4O

Comment: @YongShun Nope. This one is more difficult

Comment: This [solution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9IMeD7PujHd) may help you. The concept is the same as @ray's answer. You can start with `$unionWith` pipeline, followed by `$match` to filter, and lastly `$unset` to remove `kid` array as your expected output (1) doesn't need `kid` array.

Comment: @YongShun Would you please pose the your query if possible?

Comment: The query is posted in the previous comment's "solution" link. Or do you mean to post as answer?

Comment: @YongShun got the point. harryk you need to understand the concepts from our previous help and at least made an attempt to convert the previous solution for this one. I believe that the helpful community here will be happy to unblock you if you encounter any difficulties when adopting the previous solutions :)

Comment: @ray, unfortunately $unionWith is introduced after version 4.4. Any way to do that at 4.2?